# CURL Function - returns 200 even without file existence

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

My curl function is returning 200 if file is existing / not existing also.

I'm new to this .

Please help out.

```
function emona_curl_func ($url) {

    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
    $url = $current_url.'/';

    $ch = curl_init($url);   
    echo $ch;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo $code;
    if($code == 200){
       $status = true;
    }else{
      $status = false;
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $code;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the URL you're trying to access doesn't reply with a 200 OK even if the page doesn't exist? The site might have a "catch-all" route that simply don't set the correct http status code?

Comment: the pages which doesn't contain the file are also returning 200 . If page doesn't exist it will redirect to 404.

Comment: What does _"the pages which doesn't contain the file"_ mean? How is that different from _"If a page doesn't exist"_?

Comment: _“If page doesn't exist it will redirect to 404”_ – you mean an external redirect? You request  `http://example.com/does-not-exist`, and get _redirected_ to `http://example.com/some-404-page`? Then whoever configured this system messed this up ... it should answer with a 404 status code under the URL that was originally requested by the client. not redirect somewhere else, that is nonsense.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm using the curl function to check whether the file exists . The custom post without file upload are also returning a value 200 from the curl function .Hope you understood now ?

Comment: @CBroe Sorry , I meant 404 status code under the URL .

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still unclear, I have no idea what _"The custom post without file upload are also returning a value 200"_ means. What file upload? Btw, `echo $ch;` doesn't make sense since `curl_init()` either returns "false" or a curl handle (resource).

Comment: When you're running your script, output the generated URL it's trying to access (when it should return 404), access that URL in your browser while having your browsers development tools with the network tab open and see if it actually returns a 200 or a 404.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok , can you please tell me "How to check if a file exists from a url" using curl ??

Comment: I've told you to check your code and what the url actually returns. If you don't want to debug the code, there aren't much I can do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149988/discussion-between-chinou-and-magnus-eriksson).

Answer (score 0):

Since i was new to this curl i got confused with so many things . Finally i found the solution .

in Functions.php file ,

```
        function test_curl_func ($url) {

                $curl = curl_init($url);

                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

                $result = curl_exec($curl);

                $ret = 0;

                //if request did not fail
                if ($result !== false) {

                    //if request was ok, check response code
                    $statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

                    if ($statusCode == 200) {
                        $ret = 1;
                    }else {
                        $ret = 0;
                    }
                }
                curl_close($curl);

                return $ret;

        }
```

in my php file i have checked whether the file exists ,

```
       if (test_curl_func( $brochure_url) == 1 )
```

Checked whether the status from curl function is true. If so , displayed the corresponding file.